# Require conditionally M2O entry per hook

Tags: php, directus

I'm currently building a simple product management, which uses status to track the products status life-cycle. I've added recently a new table called "handles" which is just `product_id` and `handle` (simple text input). For simplicity:

[image]

I've create a hook.php file, which already gets loaded and works.

```php
$filter = function (Payload $payload) {
  $container = Application::getInstance()->getContainer();

  $itemsService = new ItemsService($container);
  $item = $itemsService->find('products', $payload->get('id'), ['fields' => 'status,handles.*']);

  $statuss = ['detailed'];
  if (in_array($item['data']['status'], $statuss) || in_array($payload->get('status'), $statuss)) {
    if ((!$item['data']['handles'] || !count($item['data']['handles']))) {
      throw new UnprocessableEntityException('Can not publish product without handle!');
    }

  return $payload;
}
```

This works flawlessly, as long as the order of updates is this:

1. Create new `product` with status "Draft"
2. Add new `handle` and save product
3. Switch status to "Detailed"

This works, because now I do have a "handle" and my code works (`count()` is not zero, so above check won't throw `UnprocessableEntityException`).

But what if my steps are like this:

1. Create new `product` with status "Detailed" (without any `handle`)

---

I couldn't figure out how to write my hook, so I could check the relational field which isn't saved while using `item.create.products:before`.
Any hints how I might check a relational field while it's being saved to database?

Thanks in advance! Any help is welcome!